# force ssl except on home/ index page with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache

sorry im a little poor headed when it comes to regex, i tried but failed.

can you tell me how so that the index/home page will not be in ssl? right now i have this rewrite rule that forces the entire site in ssl:

```
# force ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What i need is the home/index page is not in ssl.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want the whole site encrypting *except* the home page?

Comment: well.. actually i just want the logged in pages to be in ssl. pages that doesn't require users to be logged in doesn't have to be in ssl. So this is a start.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # force ssl
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$  # no ssl on /
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ # no ssl on index.php
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: hey... this doesn't really work. tried it any https still shows up.

Comment: @David: This code does the following: If the requested page is not the root `/` and `index.php`, and `HTTPS` is not on, it will redirect to https. Otherwise, it will leave your request as it was. If your request is `https://www.example.com/index.php`, this code will not redirect it to `http://www.example.com/index.php`. If you want to achieve the second, please let me know. Otherwise, tell me how you are testing it, and what URLs are not working?

Answer (score 0):

The right condition would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Make sure, the rewrite engine is loaded.

Comment: but what about the home/index page?

Answer (score 0):

You want another `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
```